# Setting enum value to random in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public enum Skills {
Random r= new Random();

//trying to use nextInt method in some case 
SKILLS(r.nextInt(125)+25),
VEHICLE(r.nextInt(125)+25),
ACCURACY(),WEAPONS(23),REFLEX(),
STRATEGY(),CHARISMA(),
HACKING(r.nextInt(125)+25),
SPEED(r.nextInt(125)+25),
STEALTH(r.nextInt(125)+25);
//end of skills 

private int value;
private Skills(int value){
    this.value=value;
}
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
}
```

I can't set the values of my enum to random. Later  I will give these skills to characters in my game. I can't use the nextInt method either. Why is that ? How to solve the problem and use this enum properly?

Comment: Read about enums and look at examples, then come back and ask this same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to use `enum` for this.  Remember that `enum` constants are singletons: all characters are going to be sharing the same single copy of each skill object, so all characters will have the same skill numbers.  That's probably not what you want.

It'd make more sense to just use a class with fields instead:

```
public class Skills {
    private int vehicleSkill;
    private int hackingSkill;
    // etc.

    public Skills(Random r) {
        this.vehicleSkill = r.nextInt(125)+25;
        this.hackingSkill = r.nextInt(125)+25;
        // etc.
    }

    public int getVehicleSkill() {
        return vehicleSkill;
    }

    public int getHackingSkill() {
        return hackingSkill;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

That way you can create a separate `Skills` object for each character.

Comment: Thanks , helped a lot, and after this, I am I am attaching these as the values of the person class' attributes. Like this: this.hacking=Skills.hackigSkill;??